# Why did my windows 8.1 password change?

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords

I've had a custom password for my windows 8.1 login since I installed the OS. I locked my computer last night and went to bed, and when I woke up this morning, my password somehow had been changed to my Microsoft Account password. How\why did this happen, how can I prevent this from happening again, and should I be worried about my security?

Comment: have you installed a Store app which tried to convert your local account to a Microsoft account?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, although I have realized that OneDrive is now installed, and I didn't do that either. ( I didn't install it)

Comment: look inside the PC Settings app under account if you now use a local or MicrosoftAccount

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, changing my account back to a 'local' brought everything back to 'normal'. However, that still doesn't answer my question entirely because I'd like to know HOW This happened and how to prevent it from happening again, or is this just some windows 8 bull-kakka that I'll have to live with?

Comment: I have no idea why it happened. Look inside the eventlog for details.